# Setting Makefile variable from recipe in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu

What am I doing wrong here?

```
VAR := $(INIT_DIR)

update_var:
       for com in $(COMS); do \
            instances="`grep -rl $$com $(SOME_PATH) | wc -l`"; \
            if (([ $(SOME_STRING) != $$com ])) && (([ $$instances -gt 0 ])); then \
                $(eval VAR+=$($(DIR)/$$com)) \
            fi; \
        done
.PHONY: update_var
```

I am getting this error: /bin/sh: 5: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected

Comment: What you want to do is not possible. What do you want to achieve in the end? There is probably a better solution to the overall problem. Maybe the [shell function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html) can help you.

Comment: As Roland says, not possible.  Your recipe is running in a _shell_ which is a separate process than make: make's variables cannot be modified based on the algorithm that's running in the shell.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the shell function as it would get complicated. I need to loop through subdirectories looking for certain strings in the source file and update a Flag to build.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
INSTANCES = $(shell grep -rl ${1} $(SOME_PATH) | wc -l)VAL
VAR += $(foreach COM,$(COMS), $(if $(filter-out $(COM),$(SOME_STRING)), $(if $(filter-out $(call INSTANCES, $(COM)),0VAL), (DIR)/$(COM))))
```